# TCL sorting and ignoring after a specific string

Tags: sorting, tcl

This is my 1st post so please bear with me, and thanks for looking.

I have a variable named **$rotation_list** that contains a P# and two numeric values following it. This variable is appended to multiple times creating a list.

I am attempting to sort this list, and when I reach 10, the 10 is placed after the 1 as shown below.

My main question is, how can I sort this list so the P1 to P10 are sorted in order. Can I sort but also ignore specific strings, but still retain the two numerical values at the end?

```
set rotation_list_unique [lsort -unique $rotation_list]


P1, 0.000, 0.000
P10, 90.000, 180.000 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
P2, 56.000, 179.971
P3, 85.000, 90.000
P4, 90.000, 0.000
P5, 90.000, 180.000
P6, 90.000, 90.000
P7, 95.000, 270.000
P8, 99.816, 181.918
P9, 95.000, 270.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`-dictionary`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.html#M6) option, which sorts numbers in strings in numeric order instead of lexicographically, and [`-stride N`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.html#M14), which treats the array as groups of `N` elements. Alternatively, instead of a simple list, a list of lists can be sorted using the [`-index N`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsort.html#M13) option to indicate which element in each sublist is the key to sort on (I'd go with this approach to organizing your data as it's easier to work with in general):

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require Tcl 8.6

set rotation_list {
P1, 0.000, 0.000
P10, 90.000, 180.000
P2, 56.000, 179.971
P3, 85.000, 90.000
P4, 90.000, 0.000
P5, 90.000, 180.000
P6, 90.000, 90.000
P7, 95.000, 270.000
P8, 99.816, 181.918
P9, 95.000, 270.000
}

foreach {a b c} [lsort -unique -stride 3 -dictionary $rotation_list] {
    puts "$a $b $c"
}

set rotation_list {
    {P1, 0.000, 0.000}
    {P10, 90.000, 180.000}
    {P2, 56.000, 179.971}
    {P3, 85.000, 90.000}
    {P4, 90.000, 0.000}
    {P5, 90.000, 180.000}
    {P6, 90.000, 90.000}
    {P7, 95.000, 270.000}
    {P8, 99.816, 181.918}
    {P9, 95.000, 270.000}
}

foreach line [lsort -unique -index 0 -dictionary $rotation_list] {
    puts $line
}
```

Comment: `-stride` was added in 8.6. A surprising number of people seem to still be using 8.5 or even older versions, so if that's the case you need the sublist approach with `-index`.

Comment: You can also combine `-stride` and `-index` if the element in each group you want to sort on isn't the first.